# (Yii)Datetime Validation fails

Tags: php, validation, yii

I'd like to validate form input that is datetime for article to be posted.

```
$model = new Post('update');
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Post'];

        if($model->validate()){

            //But, validation fails...    

        }
```

This is the rule that I got to check if the input is datetime format or not.
I used this page(http://chris-backhouse.com/date-validation-in-yii/528) as reference.

But I get validation error for 'created'input.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(

        //datetime validation
        array('created', 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: is not a datetime!', 'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'),

        );
}
```

This is what I have in $models-attribute.

```
array(1) { ["created"]=> string(19) "2013-08-01 00:00:01" }
```

Could anyone knows how to make this work?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice to use input formats in rule, since sometimes you want custom formats.

```
array('created', 'date', 'format'=>'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'message'=>'{attribute} have wrong format'),
```

More about date formats here - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateTimeParser

Comment: what is the difference between the rule I coded and yours?

it seems the same.

        array('created', 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: is not a datetime!', 'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'),

Comment: Date validator calls `CDateTimeParser::parse()` function with your date format. This function have strict format, and if you dont understand difference beetween uppercase and lowercase, i cant help you. It have construction like `switch($token)
   {
    case 'yyyy':
    {
     if(($year=self::parseInteger($value,$i,4,4))===false)
      return false;
     $i+=4;
     break;
    }` will your `YYYY` pass it, or will be returned false on default case? `date('d')` will return 13 and `date('D')` return `Tue`. So please next time think what you writing and read articles which people give you.

Comment: Sorry to reply you late! and Thank you very much for adding comments. although I haven't tried it yet, I think I understand how to fix my problem now.

Answer (score 1):

On Yii 2.0.6 (and maybe Yii 1.x ?), the correct format is :

```
['creation_date', 'date', 'format'=>'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss']
```

It's not working if hours are not in CAPS.

Comment: To confirm, this does work as expected in Yii 1.1.x latest although I don't know where it was added.

Answer (score 0):

Is this creation time of the post? Then you don't need to validate it at all and you should set it in beforeSave instead of sending it with POST

add this to your model:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
  if($this->isNewRecord)
  {
     $this->created=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
  }
  return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Comment: >Is this creation time of the post?

not exactly.

It can be the future time the post is scheduled to be published.